# How to create heat map from set of tracks?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, heatmap, tracking

At the moment I have a set of tracks (in separate files) in 3 dimensions. My goal is to create at least 2 2D heat maps (XY/XZ relations) from these tracks based off of how many distinct tracks cross a region of some arbitrary size. 
However, it would be ideal to have a 3D heatmap!

Lets say the region is 10x10 and the tracks span a 100x100 region (it's actually 480 x 640 in reality but 100x100 is simpler to discuss)

I have a notion of how to do this, but it involves an additional 2-3 matrices per track, and does not seem like an efficient/the easiest way to code this.

Essentially my idea revolves around processing each track individually. You start off with an appropriately sized int matrix that keeps track of how many tracks appeared in your region of interest (ROI) starting at 0 for every entry. You then have another equivalently appropriately sized matrix, but this one takes booleans, you iterate over the track list, and change the entry of the bool matrix to true if the track is in the corresponding area. Then you increment the original int matrix +1 if the bool is true in the corresponding region. You then reset everything but the int matrix and start over with a new track file. Then you can just create a graph of boxes with the intensity/color corresponding to the int matrix.

But I was wondering if there is a cleaner or more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Those tracks -- how are those represented? A list of 3D coordinates defining something like a polyline in 3D? Could you provide an expample tracks file?

Comment: The set of tracks are points separated by newlines. So like so: x1,y1,z1 \n x2,y2,z2 \n and so on. They represent a line in 3D.

Comment: Great, can you at least [edit] your post and add a few dozen lines from one of those tracks?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. I tried to paste it in the original post but it would not take into account new lines so here it is on google drive (it is just a text file). https://drive.google.com/file/d/14YQ1CpBmbl1dDM2uVhQzwnP-t5EI4tUe/view?usp=sharing